# SQL сравнение нескольких параметров в нескольких таблицах

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день, нужно сделать выборку и сравнение данных из нескольких таблиц, на данный момент есть запрос делающий половину от нужной задачи.

```
use export
SELECT 
       A.[AbonentJId]
      ,replace(ltrim(replace(ME1.[Number], '0', ' ')), ' ', 0)  
      ,ME1.[DateStart]
      ,ME1.PointNum
      ,ME1.[ValueStart]
      ,E.abonent_id
      ,E.tariff
      ,E.meter_id
 FROM [export].[dbo].[MeterEl] ME1
 inner join export.dbo.Address A on A.Id=ME1.AddressId 
 full join export.dbo.Enero E on E.abonent_id=A.AbonentJId 
                              and E.tariff=ME1.PointNum 
                              and replace(ltrim(replace(ME1.[Number], '0', ' ')), ' ', 0)= E.meter_id 
 Where A.AbonentJId is not null and ME1.[Number] is not null and E.meter_id is not NULL
 group by
       ME1.[Number]
      ,A.[AbonentJId] 
      ,ME1.[DateStart]
      ,ME1.PointNum
      ,ME1.[ValueStart]
      ,E.abonent_id
      ,E.tariff
      ,E.meter_id

 ORDER BY ME1.[Number],ME1.PointNum,A.AbonentJId
```

В общем задача такая, есть 3 таблицы MeterEl которая содержит номер счетчика Number, номер тарифа PointNum и собственно Id, вторая таблица Address содержит Id абонента и id счетчика и джойнится с ним, для того что бы можно было сравнить их с третьей таблицей Enero, которая содержит id абонента номер счетчика и номер тарифа. (Для удобства таблицы MeterEl и Address буду называть одним именем, потому что по факту они выполняют роль одной таблицы, MA). Так вот проблема состоит в том, что некоторые счетчики являются трех тарифными, некоторые двух, а некоторые однотарифные, и в таблице это выглядит как 3 строки с различием в PointNum в таблице MA для трех тарифного, 2 строки для 2-х и 1 для одного. Для одного и того же счетчика тарификация может отличаться в таблице MA и Enero. И задача для трехтарифного счетчика должны сравниваться 3 строки в таблице MA и Enero и если все 3 совпадают выводиться в селект, для 2-х тарифного должны совпадать 2 строки и для однотарифного 1. Если для трех тарифного идет расхождение хоть в одном тарифе, т.е. в таблице MA есть три строки с тарифами, а в таблице Enero 1 то результат не должен учитываться, т.е. необходимо полное совпадение. Мой запрос сейчас работает на совпадение по первому тарифу, он не отбрасывает счетчик если у него идет несхождение в тарифак 2 или 3. КАк это сделать, не городя огромнейшую конструкцию с and и or, потому что такие запросы съедают более 40 гигов в tempBD, а я себе такое позволить не могу.

Comment: А итоговая группировка какая должны быть, так же до тарифа или все таки до абонента ? Если до абонента, то такую и сделайте, а в having убедитесь что не было строк, где номер тарифа с одной или другой стороны NULL (`count(1)=count(PointNum)`)

Comment: А если группировка должна остаться как есть, то сделать такие же проверки оконными функциями (если они есть в вашей СУБД) и обернув в еще один select проверить на такое же равенство количеств

Comment: Я пришел к выводу, что можно, или даже, нужно, сравнить количество строк  с совпадением абонентский номер+номер счетчика в таблице MA и в таблице Enero, и этого будет достаточно, что бы отсеить, но проблема в том, что я не могу найти как сделать count(Number, AbonentJId) или count (Number+ AbonentJId), как это провернуть? БД MS SQL

Comment: Ясно спасибо, возможно сработает. По факту получается, что мы приводим количество записей в одной таблице, к количеству записей в другой по тарифам, я шел по другой логике, но все же, есть ли фунция подсчета спаренных значений в колонках?

Comment: *Для одного и того же счетчика тарификация может отличаться в таблице MA и Enero.* Только фактом наличия тарифа в одной и отсутствия во второй? или там ещё и некие значения должны сравниваться? Если только наличием - то с группировкой по счётчику посчитайте по каждой таблице нечто типа `SUM(CASE tariff WHEN 'tariff1' THEN 1 WHEN 'tariff2' THEN 2 WHEN 'tariff3' THEN 4 END)` (т.е. тупо битовая маска). Выражение вполне пригодно не только для отбора, но и даже для связывания считающих такие маско-суммы подзапросов.

Comment: что значит "спаренных" вы же делаете full join, он сам уже все "спарит". и оставит NULL. конечно можно написать в том же having   жуткие `sum(case when Number=AbonentJId then 0 else 1 end)` и убедится что она равна 0. но с count() как то проще. И мы не количества приводим, а как раз проверяем на NULL, потому что count(1) считает все записи, а count(number) считает количество НЕ null значений в столбце number (т.е. количество совпавших)

Comment: спаренный значит, что у одного абонентского номера может быть несколько счетчиков, а у каждого счетчика, может быть несколько абонентских номеров, т.е. если сделать count(ME1.number), то для некоторых счетчико он может выводить значения больше трех, а это не то что нужно, поэтому нам надо считать именно количество строк содержащих абонентский номер и номер счетчика

Comment: т.е. нужно считать количество срок не по одному столбцу а по 2 одновременно